# Form Array to Object into AJAX call with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form element in my html.  Inside the form I have input elements.  One of these input elements should be an array.  I want to send an object that looks something like the following.

```
obj = {
  input1: "blah",
  input2: "blah2,
  input3: [{
    a: 'abc',
    b: 'def',
    c: 'hig'
  },{
    a: 'cba',
    b: 'fed',
    c: 'gih'
  }],
  input4: "blah5"
}
```

I've tried to use this as my submit but I'm not sure how to serialize this correctly to create an object like above.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var obj = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
       method: "POST",
       url: "http://localhost/form",
       data: obj
    ...
```

Here is my HTML (modified to hide info) I have also hardcode the  elements in this example.  In realtime they would be dynamic and the user would be able to add or remove  elements via jquery functions

```
<form id="thisFormThing">
<ul role="tablist" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#globalAttributes" aria-controls="globalAttributes" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Global Attributes</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#inputs" aria-controls="inputs" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Inputs</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="globalAttributes" role="tabpanel" style="padding-top: 20px" class="tab-pane">
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="form-group"><label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Input1:</label>
                <div class="col-md-1"><input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" class="form-control"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="form-group"><label for="input2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Input2:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3"><select class="form-control"><option value="1">blah2</option><option value="2">blah3</option><option value="3">blah4</option>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="hosts" role="tabpanel" style="padding-top: 20px" class="tab-pane active">
        <table id="dataTable" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>a</th>
                    <th>b</th>
                    <th>c</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="dataBody">
                <tr id="0">
                    <td><input type="text" name="a" class="form-control"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="b" class="form-control input-sm"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="c" class="form-control"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="1">
                    <td><input type="text" name="a" class="form-control"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="b" class="form-control input-sm"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="c" class="form-control"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="form-actions"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try changing the names to `input3[0][a]`  ... `input3[1][a]` format

Comment: I hardcode the <tr>'s in this example.  In the live version the <tr> element will be dynamic.  The user will be able to add and remove <tr> elements so hardcoding the array index will not work in this case

Comment: So you can dynamically create the names based on row index. Alternatively map the rows and build an object for each row to pass into map() array

Answer (score -2):

One possible solution is to use a textarea instead of an input (for more confortable typing) and parsing it for comma separated strings:

```
// Assuming the string the user types is "asd, asd2, asd3"
// Trim it before splitting to remove whitespaces
string.trim().split(','); // Outputs ["asd", "asd2", "asd3"]
```

You can tell the user what syntax is expected so you know how to parse the resulting string.

Caveats:

- You might need to also trim newlines and all whitespace prior to  splitting. The answer to that is in stackOverflow.
- To do multiple objects you can either use multiple inputs or define a syntax that allows the user to define objects in a string, then parse it multiple times from bigger to smaller structures.